# Using javascript functions in a php code

Tags: javascript, php, function, call, sajax

I got a question considering some php code i'm working with.
In the code i got a function definde with 3 input values (as shown at the very bottom), that is called somewhere else in the programm with an x_ preceded. 
Furthermore it is called with 4 values even though the function definition only includes 3 values. The 4th value appears to me to be related with some javascript code, cause it calls a function in an .js document. (unfortunately im not familiar at all with js up to now)

Now im wondering why the function is called with the preceding x_* and what the 4th value passed to the function is doing?

The programm also includes sajax which i dont know at all, but maybe this helps providing an answer.

I appreciate a lot your help!

The code of the javascript file is the following:

```js
function assign_projekt_cb(data) {
    alert(data["meldung"]);
}
```

In the php code the function is called by the following code:

```php
echo " onClick=\"x_assign_recht('".$row["idUser"]."', 'download', this.checked, assign_recht_cb)\">";
```

and defined as follows:

```php
function assign_recht($user, $recht, $value) {
    if (rechtecheck("adminadmin",true)) {
        if ($value == 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE `User` SET `$recht` = 1 WHERE `idUser` LIKE '$user';";
            $meldung = "Passt! $recht = 1 bei User $user";
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE `User` SET `$recht` = 0 WHERE `idUser` LIKE '$user';";
            $meldung = "Passt! $recht = 0 bei User '$user'";
        }
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error manipulating information. " . mysql_error());
        return array("meldung" => $meldung, "idartikel" => $idartikel);
    }
}
```

I'm new to the forum and just started learning php. Now im working on that particular php code using a js code at only one point what makes it pretty difficult for me to interpret that code segment at that specific point, cause of the lack of knowledge in js programming. On the other hand i dont have the capabilities right now to get familiar with java, so i hoped someone here can help me understand that code a bit better.

Please forgive the poorly formulation of the question, im not yet familiar with the common terminology neither, since im a lateral entrant to programming!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `assign_recht` is a **php** function. `x_assign_recht` is a **javascript** function. They are completely separate functions that can do completely different things. The nameing suggests they are related in some way, buts that all

Comment: You're not providing enough information. Where is `x_assign_recht()` defined?

Comment: Wow, thank first of all for the quick responses!

"Where is x_assign_recht() defined?"
That actually hits the nail perfectly, since thats my problem, cause im not sure bout where x_assign_rechte is defined(i couldnt find any defintion). So i suggerated that x_assign_recht calles the function defined through "function assign_recht" only with maybe varying parameters or something like that.

Comment: Or is there any possibility of code that modifies the function definition in a predefinde way in the sence of adding the x_* parameter to the defintion causes a 4th value to be added?

The code uses sajax at some point aswell which i cant associate to anything.

Comment: `x_assign_recht`, as i stated, is a javascript function. Therefor it will be defined in javascript somewhere. Either a .js file or embeded into a php/html file in <script></script> tags. Understand that javascript and php are completely different langages, and can only interact via http (eg ajax).

Comment: Ok thanks for that. If i start searching the .js files in my project i cant find a java function called x_assign_recht anywhere. It looks to me as if the function is not defined, is that possible somehow?

Furthermore it appears to me that the defined function, "assign_recht" is exactly doing what i would expect to be done when x_assign_recht is called, in the sence of returning the statement ""Passt! $recht = 1 bei User $user"" that is afterwards popping up in a new window, appearently when the java script "assign_projekt_cb(data)" is called.

Comment: @Hannes089 OK, heres what i think is happening, based on the function names and guesswork! `x_assign_recht` is a javascript function that makes an ajax request to a php file that calls the php function `assign_recht`. I believe the `x_` prefix is an allusion to aja**x**. the forth parameter to that function is a reference to another javascript function that will be executed when the ajax call complete. These type of functions are commonly called **callbacks** in js, hence the suffix assign_projekt_ **cb** What does this mean? Well you still have to find `x_assign_recht` it is defined somewhere

Comment: Thanks for that so far.
As i found out now, x_ is related to the fact that the fundtion is called via sajax.
So the function x_assign_recht calls the php function defined as assign_recht using sajax, somehow like that.

Thanks for your answers